# Is it possible to start an Xcode Cloud workflow from a comment left on a PR?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, testflight, xcode-cloud

I'm trying to reduce the number of builds getting sent to TestFlight because I sometimes make multiple commits my PRs. Is it possible to setup a bot or web hook to trigger an Xcode Cloud workflow?

The documentation seems to say

```
You can configure up to four different start conditions for an Xcode Cloud workflow:
- Branch Changes
Xcode Cloud starts a new build if any branch, a specific branch, or several configured branches change.

- Pull Request Changes
Xcode Cloud starts a new build if you create a new pull request (PR) or if you update an existing PR.

- Tag Changes
Xcode Cloud starts a new build if you create or update a Git tag.

- On a Schedule for a Branch
Xcode Cloud starts a new build on a configured schedule.
```

Are there any work arounds to allow me to `@bot-name build` for example on the PR and have it start the Build and upload to TestFlight workflow?

Thanks!

I tried reading the documentation and adding a GitHub hook.

Comment: You can add start conditions with tag changes. so that only when you add specific tag , build get started.